# Should we create index on date or datetime column in relational databases?

Tags: database, indexing

Assuming a column with timestamp is used in many select queries, should we have a index on that column? What are the cons for it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying on it, then definitely. Otherwise you need a table scan to find the rows. Con is it might be a big index, but only consideration is whether the needs of the many (every update having to update an index - very small impact) outweigh the needs of the few (the otherwise very long queries). Unlikely.

Comment: This is general indexing technique. I want to know particularly for date and datetime field indexing. Should we have index on datetime fields. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, if you are querying against it. No choice.